# Meaning of (?s) in regex

Tags: regex, powershell, expression

I am very new to the regular expression arena.  Recently I searched for a regular expression for Powershell that allows me to match a html tag  and I found the following in this site.

```
$content -match '(?s)<table[^>]+width\s*=\s*"300px"\s*.*?>(.*?)</table>'
```

I have been looking for all regular expressions references and books (Perl and Powershell) for the meaning of (?s) with no luck. It looks like a condition but missing the then part.

Can someone point me to the right direction for the meaning of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 29):

According to [Regular Expressions reference site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html).

> Turn on "dot matches newline" for the remainder of the regular
>   expression. (Older regex flavors may turn it on for the entire regex.)

Comment: oh.. thanks a lot.  All my references only list out (?i) for case sensitivity, although some of references do mentioned single-line mode, multi-line mode, and free-spacing mode too, but they don't mention the syntex.

Comment: The relevant regex reference site page is (now) [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html).

Answer (score 2):

(?x) in the beginning of a regex, where "x" is some letter, turns on or off different behaviours.

See https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: It would have been useful to include that, `(?s)` at the start of a regular expression turns on `'single-line-mode'`, e.g. regex `abc.def` would match the string "abcXdef" where "X" can be any character except a newline. Regex `(?s)abc.def` would match "abcXdef" where "X" could be any character, including a newline.

Answer (score -1):

"?" means 1 or 0 matches. "?s" enables dot matching newlines. A period is normally a wildcard that will match any character, save the newline.

Comment: ? must have a preceding character. In this case, only ( precedes ?, and as for the period, I would say there is none.