# Remove code render blocks (<% %>) and their content across multiple lines

Tags: regex, powershell

I am using Powershell's `-Replace` option on a string. I loaded the variable `$content` with the text from a file using `Get-Content`. Here is a sample of the text in the string variable `$content`:

```
I want to keep this text,
<%
    Response.Cookies("abcebklocn") = "0"
    Response.Cookies("lastpage") = "76"
    srchterms=Request.QueryString("srch")
%> and also keep this text.
```

I am trying to delete all instances of the code render block (`"<%...%>"`) and the content within it, but the command I am using removes neither the tags nor the multiline content. Here is the command:

```
$content = $content -replace "<%\n\r+([\s\S]*?)%>\n\r+",""
```

Comment: What tool are you trying to do this with?

Comment: You need some sort of multiline flag. What language/text editor are you using?

Comment: Trim those stars off the side and you might get a step closer, provided we're talking standard regular expressions.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the ** I thought were a product of the wiki mark-up to bold. I am using this regex in Powershell.

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Comment: I am still struggling with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you have so far will probably only look for those markers within a single line.

Something like this might do the trick. The `(?s)` flag at the start allows `.` to match newline characters, and is [apparently supported by Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927930/meaning-of-s-in-regex).

```
$content = $content -replace '(?s)<%.*?%>',''
```

Perhaps now that I've tagged your question correctly you might get an answer from someone who knows what they're talking about though. :)