# R tidyr extract doesn't capture multiline expressions

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a tibble with a multiline string, and I want to use `tidyr::extract` to extract variables using regex groups, where the values are multiline strings. In the following example, however, I don't extract the `-`-separated groups.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = "12\n34-56\n78-90\n12")

my_regex <- regex("(.*)-(.*)-(.*)", multiline = TRUE, dotall = TRUE)

extract(df, x, c("y", "z", "a"), my_regex)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   y     z     a    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

There's nothing wrong with the regex itself, as illustrated by `stringr::str_view`.

```
str_view(df$x, my_regex)
```

**Is this a known bug or feature of `tidyr::extract`?** (Note that my actual problem is more complex, and not amenable to `tidyr::separate` like this one is.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*tidyr* just doesn't support the output from *stringr::regex* It's not a bug, see : https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/749 and https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/693

You can do :

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = "12\n34-56\n78-90\n12")
extract(df, x, c("y", "z", "a"), regex = "(?s)(.*)-(.*)-(.*)")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   y        z        a       
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 "12\n34" "56\n78" "90\n12"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Excellent, thank you. For those wondering, the `(?s)` at the start of the regex ensures that `.` matches newline (`\n`) characters, without needing to use `dotall = TRUE`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927930/meaning-of-s-in-regex for more info.

Comment: _tidyr just doesn't support the output from stringr::regex_ seems incorrect. Its not that tidyr doesnot support the output, but rather the `.` does not match linebreaks, you would have to have the regex in a single line mode ie `(?s)` instead of the default multiline mode

Comment: Wouldn't the option `dotall = TRUE` handle that if *tidyr* did support that output ?